# Fixing 'backwards' git merge that was pushed

Tags: git, version-control, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have run into a problem between my git branches that I'm not sure how to approach.  Let's say I have separate branches for each release I'm working on.  For example, I have 'Release-1' and 'Release-2' as my branches.  These releases are sequential in nature, that is 'Release-2' contains everything in 'Release-1,' but not the other way around.  In my case, I accidentally merged 'Release-2' into 'Release-1' and pushes it without realizing my mistake.  One I realized that I made a mistake, I went ahead and issued:

```
git revert -m 1 <sha-of-bad-merge-commit>
```

This appeared to fix everything; none of the 'Release-2' code was in 'Release-1' and all appeared correct.  I pushed this to my upstream thinking it was resolved.  Fast forward to today.  I have applied a bug fix in the 'Release-1' branch.  Now, I want to merge 'Release-1' into 'Release-2,' but I'm running into conflits.  Git thinks that the changes made in the revert from before should be merged into 'Release-2.'  Essentially, git wants to remove the changes from 'Release-2' that accidentally got introduced into 'Release-1' from 'Release-2' when I try to merge.

I've tried researching a solution and haven't found one.  The closest I've found applied to merging too early, reverting, and then trying to merge again at a later date.  The solution was to revert the revert and then do the merge again.  I don't think that will work in this case, because that would re-introduce the changes into 'Release-1' that are not meant to be in 'Release-1.'

Other than looking through each affected file line-by-line to select the correct set of changes, is there a good 'git-based' way to approach this?  I don't want to simply take the changes from the 'Release-2' branch where there are conflicts, as some of them could be legitimate.  Also, I've considered just merging in the bug fix branch to 'Release-2,' but then the problem will likely come up again in the future.  I'd like to prevent that from happening.

Here's a rough drawing of the situation:

```
(Release-2) ---A----B----C---x---x---------*D*
                          \               /
(Release-1) ---x----Y------M---x---^M----Z
```

Assume A, B, and C are normal commits that I want for 'Release-2.'  The tip of 'Release-1' is Y and contains only 'Release-1' work.  Commit 'M' is where I accidentally merge commit 'C' and commit 'Y' in the 'Release-1' branch.  At some point, I notice my mistake and revert the merge (commit '^M').  Commit 'Z' then has my hotfix in it.  At this point I want to merge 'Release-1' back into 'Release-2.'  I do this and end up at 'D.'  This is where I have my problem.  Essentially, my merge at 'D' is telling it wants to delete all of the changes made in 'A,' 'B,' and 'C,' which I don't want.  Other files are showing up as conflicts due to the merge revert.  For example, some files that I want in 'Release-2' were deleted in 'Release-1' when I did the revert.  Now, at 'D,' git is telling me there is a merge conflict because one branch deleted the file and the other modified the file.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would much appreciate hearing them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm going to refer to your `^M` commit as `Mrevert`, since the `^` character has special meaning in some of the commands that follow.)

Do `git merge --abort` to abandon your attempt to create commit `D`.

Since you have a series of commits `x--Mrevert--Z`, and you need to pull in `x` and `Z`'s changes, but not `Mrevert`'s, you need a three-step process:

1. Use `git merge Mrevert^` to pull in all the changes up to the point of `Mrevert`.  (The `c^` syntax means "the parent of commit `c`".)
2. Use `git merge -s ours Mrevert` to tell git that the changes from the `^M` reversion commit are already in your branch.  `-s ours` means to keep our (i.e. Release-2's) version of the tree, not bothering with any real "merging".
3. Use `git merge Z` to merge in the changes from `Z`.

This will produce a commit graph like:

```
(Release-2) ---A----B----C---x---x---M1-----M2------M3
                          \         /      /       /
(Release-1) ---x----Y------M-------x---Mrevert----Z
```

If you do `git diff M1 M2`, you'll see that `M2` does not pull any changes into Release-2.

Comment: This is *mostly* right and would be *completely* right if only that commit marked `x` between `M` and `^M` were not there.  I think the way to do this is to do *three* merges instead of two: one to merge in commit `x`, one with `-s ours` to merge `^M`, and the last to merge in commit `Z`.

Comment: @Matt Thanks a bunch!  This solution worked as expected.  The reason that I used the '^' symbol with the 'M' revert was that I was following the same kind of illustration as the ones located here: https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html

Comment: @torek I didn't notice any issues in the 'x' commit when I followed the instructions Matt provided.  I think that this is because the revert commit doesn't impact the 'x' at all, so it still gets merged as expected later.  There were some commits in 'M' that I *did* want in 'Release-1.0' that got reverted in '^M,' so I had to do some extra work (a cherry-pick of the commit after the revert) to get those changes in at Z.

Comment: It's possible that you don't need, or do get via another path, the changes from that commit.  The basic idea with the `--ours` merge is to record the merge in the commit graph (so that the *next* merge comes up with the right merge base) while completely ignoring all the changes that the merge would normally add, and that includes the changes in that `x` commit, so you won't get them from `x` itself later.